# ERROR TypeError: _co.onBlueprintAdded is not a function

Tags: angular

cockpit.component.ts . . . ... . . ... . . . . .... .  . . .
.... ......... ....... ........ . . ... .. . ..... . ... . . ...  . . ...

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cockpit',
  templateUrl: './cockpit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cockpit.component.css']
})
export class CockpitComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() serverCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string}>();
  @Output() blueprintCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverContent: string}>();
  newServerName = '';
  newServerContent = '';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onAddServer() {
    this.serverCreated.emit(
      {serverName: this.newServerName,
        serverContent: this.newServerContent
      });
  }

  onAddBlueprint() {
    this.blueprintCreated.emit(
      {serverName: this.newServerName,
        serverContent: this.newServerContent
      });
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain why I get the following error? I'm a beginner in angular.

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{
    type: 'server',
    name: 'Testserver',
    content: 'Just a Test!!'
  }];


  onServerAdded(serverData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string}) {
    this.serverElements.push({
      type: 'server',
      name: serverData.serverName,
      content: serverData.serverContent
    });
  }

  onBlueprintAdded(blueprintData: {serverName: string, serverContent: string}) {
    this.serverElements.push({
      type: 'blueprint',
      name: blueprintData.serverName,
      content: blueprintData.serverContent
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <app-cockpit
    (serverCreated)="onServerAdded($event)"
    (blueprintCreated)="onBlueprintAdded($event)"
  ></app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <app-server-element
       *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
       [element]="serverElement"
     ></app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error in the console:

```
AppComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: _co.onBlueprintAdded is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppComponent.html:4)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:12023)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13493)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13081)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8615)
    at core.es5.js:10783
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.es5.js:3647)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
```

bear with me still need to write some stuffs before i can post the question

Comment: Can you provide some code showing how you are emmiting data from the `cockpit.component.ts`.

Comment: Your question header has a different error than in your question? Which is it? Could you please create a demo (plunker, stackblitz ?) that showcases your issue.

Comment: Yeah, could you create a demo for this, I see no obvious error so would be good if you could recreate it :)

Comment: @TOLULOPEADETULA Does this only happens when you trigger some event ? e.g when you click a button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just re run the ng serve  again, it will make the new Bundle

Answer (score 0):

Declaration needed in `cockpit.component.ts` is

```
serverElement=[];
```

changes function name in app.component.ts

```
onServerAdded to onAddServer
onBlueprintAdded to onAddBluePrint
```

changes in app.component.html

```
(serverCreated)="onAddServer($event)"
(blueprintCreated)="onAddBluePrint($event)"
```

Hope your cockpit.component.ts is like this below

input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">
input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newServerContent">
button (click)="onAddServer()" >Add Server
button (click)="onAddBluePrint()">Add Blueprint

Answer (score 0):

While copying the class details, the properties and methods one might have pasted on the wrong file, for example on app-routing.module.ts instead of app.component.ts which is where the functionality is being looked for by Angular.